# Quartz HelloJob

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am new to Quartz and I'm running into a compiling error. I am simply trying to get the HelloJob to run based on Quartz's Lesson 1 for Hello World. I am having trouble declaring a `JobDetail` with the error: `The method newJob(Class<? extends Job>)` in the type `JobBuilder` is not applicable for the arguments (Class)".

Originally, the code had 3 errors at `newJob`, `newTrigger`, and `simpleSchedule` was

```
// define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
JobDetail job = newJob(HelloJob.class)
    .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
    .build();

// Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 40 seconds
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
    .startNow()
    .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
            .withIntervalInSeconds(40)
            .repeatForever())            
    .build();
```

without JobBuilder.newJob(...), TriggerBuilder.newTrigger(...), SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule(...). Unlike the example given, I went ahead and added the imports and attached the class calls in front of newJob, newTrigger, etc. which got rid of 2/3 errors. But it seems the error persists with

```
 JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob.class)
        .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
        .build();
```

I have also tried replacing my job declaration with

```
JobDetail job = new JobDetail("job1", "group1", HelloJob.class);
```

but that ends with `Cannot instantiate the type JobDetail` and it seems like a few examples out there do this.

Will really appreciate clarification,

Thanks!

Comment: can u post the class "HelloJob"

Comment: Yeah, it was in my HelloJob not implementing Job. Sorry for making a silly mistake!

Comment: Thanks for asking this question; I had the same problem and it was great to find this solution. It seems a shame that the quartz documentation is a little buggy.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to have this line of code:

```
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.*;
```

And then in should work.  Hopefully.

Edit:
AND MAKE SURE 'HELLOJOB' IMPLEMENTS JOB!!

There.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add below four imports for helloJob examples to work for quart 2.2.x

```
import org.quartz.SimpleTrigger;
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.newJob;
import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.newTrigger;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
public class HelloJob implements Job {

@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println("Simple Exapmle");

 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quartz 2 APIs are big different with Quartz 1(1.5,1.6  and 1.7) Class JobDetail{
}

quartz-1.6.6:
http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/quartz/quartz-1.6.6/org/quartz/JobDetail.html

Quartz 2:

```
public interface JobDetail extends Serializable, Cloneable {
}

// we have to create JobDetail in the below way.
JobDetail job = newJob(HelloJob.class)

// we have to create Trigger in the below way.
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
```

Don't forget to import the below one

```
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

1-

> Quartz provides “builder” classes that define a Domain Specific Language

You can import the missing DSL's through:

```
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.*;
```

2- Make sure that `HelloJob` class implements `org.quartz.Job` not any other Job:

```
  public class HelloJob implements org.quartz.Job{

     public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException{
       System.out.println("Hello!  HelloJob is executing.");
     }
  }
```

You can find a [tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-02.html) in the quartz documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more detailed description of this example on this [website](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/). There, you can find the libraries that are necessary to import, as well as the implementation of job in the class HelloJob.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Implement `HelloJob.class` with the `Job` interface

using

```
import org.quartz.Job;

public class HelloJob implements Job {

}
```